# Play + Scala + Reactivemongo + Rest Query with 2 params

Tags: mongodb, scala, play-reactivemongo

I downloaded the typesafe application "modern-web-template", which implements a crud application with play + scala + reactivemongo

I was trying to add a new functionality. I want to be able by calling a URL with two params like this

```
localhost:9000/users?dni&30000000
```

first I added this route to the routes file

```
GET     /users                      @controllers.Users.findUsersParams(tipoDocumento: String ?= "", numeroDocumento:  String ?= "")
```

Then I added this method to the controller

```
def findUsersParams(tipoDocumento: String, numeroDocumento: String) = Action.async {
// let's do our query
val cursor: Cursor[User] = collection.
  // find all
  find(Json.obj("tipoDocumento" -> tipoDocumento, "numeroDocumento" -> numeroDocumento)).
  // sort them by creation date
  sort(Json.obj("created" -> -1)).
  // perform the query and get a cursor of JsObject
  cursor[User]

// gather all the JsObjects in a list
val futureUsersList: Future[List[User]] = cursor.collect[List]()

// transform the list into a JsArray
val futurePersonsJsonArray: Future[JsArray] = futureUsersList.map { users =>
  Json.arr(users)
}
// everything's ok! Let's reply with the array
futurePersonsJsonArray.map {
  users =>
    Ok(users(0))
}
}
```

I am not able to return the expected result that should be one user, instead, I am getting all the users inside the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your Query, it should be

```
http://localhost:9000/users?tipoDocumento=dni&numeroDocumento=30000000
```

Other than that code seems fine, and should be working.

Comment: thanks for your answers. The right URL is the one you posted, but still not working, keeps me retrieving all the users.

Comment: Maybe you have overlapping mapping, check in debug, that you actually reach this method.

Comment: Thank you @mavarazy was that, routes were overlapping mapping. I changed one of the routes name and worked perfectly.